# Floating nav buttons and margin 0 auto not displaying correctly

Tags: html, css

I'm building a nav bar for my site. The site has 3 buttons. One on the left one on the center and one on the right. I have the left button floating left. The center button has margin: 0 auto to center it and the right button is floated right. There is a problem with the right button not sitting in the navigation bar. Its over flowing out of the bar. I have attached an image showing this.
[image: Css Nav Problem]

Comment: You’ll need to put the last button before the middle one in the HTML code, only then floating it to the right will work as you want it to. // And please go read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess from your html markup that the right button is literally last, move it to be first, I.e before the left floated element, and it will sit as you expect

Comment: Would this make the right floating button sit before centered button? I want the right floated button to be sitting at the very end of the navigation

Comment: Thanks! this worked. Can anyone explain why it must be done this way?